# Homeomorphism between open and closed integer intervals

Tags: general-topology

> There are 2 topological spaces:
>
> $\mathcal{T}_1$ consists of $\mathbb{R}$, $\emptyset$, and every interval $(−n,n)$, for n any positive integer;
>
> $\mathcal{T}_2$ consists of $\mathbb{R}$, $\emptyset$, and every interval $[−n,n]$, for n any positive integer;

I was thinking that the spaces were not homeomorphic but than I constructed a homeomorphism using induction:

1. For n = 1. The intervals are homeomorphic $[-1, 1] \cong (-1, 1)$

$$
f: [-1, 1] \rightarrow (-1, 1)\\
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{2} & \text{for } x = -1 \\
\frac{1}{2} & \text{for } x = 1 \\
-\frac{x}{2} & \text{for } x = -\frac{1}{2^n}\\
\frac{x}{2} & \text{for } x = \frac{1}{2^n}\\
x & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

2. Given that $(-n, n) \cong [-n, n]$ we can prove that $(-(n+1), n+1) \cong [-(n+1), n+1]$. We need to find bijection for the tails. Bijection for the left tail $(-(n+1), -n] \cong [-(n+1), -n)$

$$
f(x) = -x - 2n - 1
$$

Similar for the right tail.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @dbx  What does compactness have to do with this?  Every bounded subset is compact within both spaces.  In fact, the closed sets are not compact since they are not bounded.

Comment: @WilliamElliot fair enough. I skimmed the question, my mistake.

Comment: Where is  that homeomorphism?  Do not tell me it is between [-n,n] and (-n,n) which are both compact and open within their respective spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your construction looks OK.

More generally, let $f$ be any bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f([-n,n])=(-n,n)$, for all positive integers $n$, and let $g=f^{-1}$.

Then $f$ is continuous, as a function from $(\mathbb{R},\tau_2)$ to $(\mathbb{R},\tau_1)$, since for all positive integers $n$, 
$$f^{-1}((-n,n))=[-n,n]$$
and $g$ is continuous, as a function from $(\mathbb{R},\tau_1)$ to $(\mathbb{R},\tau_2)$, since for all positive integers $n$,
$$g^{-1}([-n,n])=(-n,n)$$