# Homeomorphism between open and closed real intervals

Tags: general-topology

> There are 2 topological spaces:
>
> $\mathcal{T}_1$ consists of $\mathbb{R}$, $\emptyset$, and every interval $(−r,r)$, for r any positive real;
>
> $\mathcal{T}_2$ consists of $\mathbb{R}$, $\emptyset$, and every interval $[−r,r]$, and every interval $(−r,r)$, for r any positive real;

Is it possible to build a homeomorphism between $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_2)$ ?

Comment: Are these topologies? Because $\mathcal{T}_2$ does not satisfy the arbitrary union property, so it's not a topology.

Comment: @BobJones I fixed the question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\mathcal{T}_2$, there are nonempty open sets which are still open after removing two points (e.g., remove $-1$ and $1$ from $[-1,1]$).

But that is not the case for $\mathcal{T}_1$. Removing two points from a nonempty open set of $\mathcal{T}_1$ yields a set which is not open.

Answer (score 3):

No, the spaces are not homeomorphic. One reason is because $\mathcal T_2$ has non-empty compact open subsets (the closed intervals $[-r,r]$) while $\mathcal T_1$ does not.

Comment: Is it possible to prove without notion of compact set?

Comment: @Andreo If you don't like compactness, then consider this: $[-r,r]$ cannot be written as the union of proper subsets. Such open sets do not exist in $\mathcal T_1$.

Comment: I study one book and compactness is introduced in subsequent chapters.

Comment: > $[−r,r]$  cannot be written as the union of proper subsets. Such open sets do not exist in $\mathcal{T}_1$

What's a difference between real intervals and integer intervals? In case of [integer intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2666995/homeomorphism-between-open-and-closed-integer-intervals) homeomorphism is possible

Comment: @Andreo In that case, you have the freedom to make a homeomorphism swap around as you wish the elements in any interval $[n,n+1)$ and $(-n-1,-n]$ to make the homeomorphism work. In this case, that would mess up intervals like $(-n-0.5,n+0.5)$, so we do not have that freedom.